# How to create custom View without subclassing from UIView

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm hoping someone could help me.

I'm wondering if it was possible to create a custom View without subclassing from UIView. The reason being I wish to have just the bare minimum of functions that I need without all the other clutter that you find in UIView.

Is this possible or am I strictly bound to making all possible Subclasses I wish to create come from UIView? If this is the case is it possible for me to hide some of the functions and attributes in UIView from outside observers and only reveal what I need revealed?

Comment: If it is a custom view, then by definition, it is a kind of `UIView`, so you can do all the things that you can do to a `UIView`, to your custom view. In short, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can design the view in storyboard and have the code in viewController. Depends on how you want to design your program and if you want to reuse your custom view.